# EventMachine how to write keyboard handler reacting on keypress

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I use EventMachine LineText2 protocol and I would like to fire `receive_line` method everytime I press a character on my keyboard and not just when I enter a new line. Is there a way to change that default behaviour?

```
class KeyboardHandler < EM::Connection
  include EM::Protocols::LineText2

  def initialize(q)
    @queue = q
  end

  def receive_line(data)
    @queue.push(data)
  end
end

EM.run {
  q = EM::Queue.new

  callback = Proc.new do |line|
    # puts on every keypress not on "\n"
    puts line
    q.pop(&callback)
  end
  q.pop(&callback)

  EM.open_keyboard(KeyboardHandler, q)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to receive unbuffered input from the terminal, you should turn off canonical-mode on standard input. (I also turn off echo to make the screen easier to read.) Add this before your code calls `#open_keyboard` or within your handler initializer:

```
require 'termios'
# ...
attributes = Termios.tcgetattr($stdin).dup
attributes.lflag &= ~Termios::ECHO # Optional.
attributes.lflag &= ~Termios::ICANON
Termios::tcsetattr($stdin, Termios::TCSANOW, attributes)
```

For example:

```
require 'termios'
require 'eventmachine'

module UnbufferedKeyboardHandler
  def receive_data(buffer)
    puts ">>> #{buffer}"
  end
end

EM.run do
  attributes = Termios.tcgetattr($stdin).dup
  attributes.lflag &= ~Termios::ECHO
  attributes.lflag &= ~Termios::ICANON
  Termios::tcsetattr($stdin, Termios::TCSANOW, attributes)

  EM.open_keyboard(UnbufferedKeyboardHandler)
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thx. It would be helpful to mention that requires a gem though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an update for Ruby 2.0+. In Ruby 2.0 we have `io/console`, which makes handling raw keyboard much easier, and it's cross-platform.

Here's a working example that reacts to raw keyboard events using `io/console`:

```
require 'io/console'
require 'eventmachine'

module KB
  def receive_data(key)
    puts "GOT: #{key}\r"

    # CTRL-C will not work in raw mode, so we need another way to exit.    
    EM::stop if key == 'q'
  end
end

begin
  EM.run {
    # Put console in raw mode (no echo, no line buffering).
    IO.console.raw!
    EM.open_keyboard(KB)
  }
ensure
  # Ensure cooked, otherwise console will be unusable after exit.
  IO.console.cooked!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used EventMachine before, but [this page on the EventMachine wiki](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/docs/KEYBOARD.html) seems to indicate that you should not use the `LineText2` protocol as it sounds like you don't want buffered lines.

They give this example:

```
module MyKeyboardHandler
  def receive_data(keystrokes)
    puts "I received the following data from the keyboard: #{keystrokes}"
  end
end

EM.run {
  EM.open_keyboard(MyKeyboardHandler)
}
```

Does that give you what you want?

Comment: No, I still have to insert "\n" in order to `receive_data`. I've found a way around using highline gem and `EM.defer` to not brake the reactor, but I'm not fully satisfied with this solution.